# OpenLayers extent to Google bounds

Tags: openlayers-2, geocoding

Could you please help me to convert OpenLayers (srid 3943) extend to Google bounds. I want to geocode from address in my map area so I do this:

```
var googleProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = document.getElementById("geocodeAddress").value;
popupGeo.destroy();

var northEast = new OpenLayers.LonLat(map.maxExtent.right,map.maxExtent.top);
var southWest = new OpenLayers.LonLat(map.maxExtent.left, map.maxExtent.bottom);
var convertedNorthEast = new northEast.transform(map.getProjectionObject(), googleProjection);
var convertedSouthWest = new southWest.transform(map.getProjectionObject(), googleProjection);
var googleBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(convertedSouthWest, convertedNorthEast);

//var convertedBounds = map.maxExtent.transform(map.getProjectionObject(), googleProjection);
//var googleBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
//    new google.maps.LatLng(convertedBounds.bottom, convertedBounds.left),
//    new google.maps.LatLng(convertedBounds.top, convertedBounds.right));//, 'bounds': googleBounds

geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        var newCenter4326 = new OpenLayers.LonLat(results[0].geometry.location.lng(), results[0].geometry.location.lat());
        var newCenter = newCenter4326.transform(googleProjection, map.getProjectionObject());

        map.setCenter(newCenter, GPSLocationZoomLevel);

    } else {
        alert("Impossible de déterminer la position : " + status);
    }
});
```

but I get an error Phi2z no convergence when I try to convert OpenLayers corners to Google epsg4326

Comment: Google uses 3857 (once known as 900913).

Comment: i also try 900913 but it didn't work i have an error when i try to convert from 3943 to 4326.

Comment: i update my code to be more readable

Answer (score 1):

I use openlayer 2.13 wich doesn't work when trying to transform 3943->4326. If i use directly Proj4js it work fine

```
   var googleProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = document.getElementById("geocodeAddress").value;
popupGeo.destroy();


var northEast = new Proj4js.Point(map.maxExtent.right, map.maxExtent.top);//On appelle la librairie Proj4js qui permet notament des transformations de projection.
var southWest = new Proj4js.Point(map.maxExtent.left, map.maxExtent.bottom);
var source = new Proj4js.Proj('EPSG:3943');//On déclare une projection source
var dest = new Proj4js.Proj('EPSG:4326');//On déclare une projection de destination.

Proj4js.transform(source, dest, northEast);
Proj4js.transform(source, dest, southWest);
var googleBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(southWest.y, southWest.x),
                                                new google.maps.LatLng(northEast.y, northEast.x));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/, The bounds parameter defines the latitude/longitude coordinates of the southwest and northeast corners of this bounding box using a pipe (|) character to separate the coordinates.

According to http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/LonLat-js.html OpenLayers defines OpenLayers.LonLat as a longitude and latitude pair.

Could it be that you need to **flip** the OpenLayers longitude and latitude pairs to be latitude longitude pairs?

Comment: convertedNorthEast is not calculated the error was phi2z no convergence. It occur before i use it in google bounds construction

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your EPSG:3943 projection params are wrong: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3943/

Several other posts referring to you error point out that their projection parameters were wrong: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/geomoose-users/2012-January/003711.html

I've never tried this but it looks like you can define a custom projection in OpenLayers, see this post: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Documentation/Dev/proj4js

I think you can define a projection in OL like this for EPSG:3943:

```
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:3943"] = "+proj=lcc +lat_1=42.25 +lat_2=43.75 +lat_0=43 +lon_0=3 +x_0=1700000 +y_0=2200000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs";
```